# In MVC pattern Problem Sending Entry value from tk.toplevel class to controller in Tkinter and Python

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel

I have implemented a MVC pattern . I have a main window which has a menu item "File", an Entry wiget and Button1. On clicking the File and then otherwin option a new window opens up. This second window also has an Entry wiget and a button. There are two classes in the view.py namely View and genTool.
When i click the Button 1 on main window i can access the  controller.py methods. But on the second window I cannot access the controller.py methods. [issue solved by implementing suggestion by @Reblochon Masque]
Second issue is receiving the data from entry wiget of genTool class in controller class.
Please suggest solution. Below is minimum viable code.

controller.py  - Run this file as python3 controller.py
[Edits suggested by @stovfl]

```
from model import Model
from view import View

class Controller:
    def __init__(self):
        self.model= Model()
        self.view= View(self)
        self.genTool=None


    def main(self):

        self.view.main()
#@stovfl
    def on_button_click(self,  caption):
        print(f' Inside controller  data for {caption} recieved')
        if self.view.gen_tool is not None:
            self.gen_tool=genTool()

        self.model.value1=self.view.value_var1   
        result= self.model.recogniseButton(caption)
        self.view.value_var1.set(result)


# old varient
    #def on_button_click(self,  caption):
        #print(f' Inside controller  data for {caption} recieved')
        #self.model.value1=self.view.value_var1  
        #self.model.value2= self.view.value_var2  # **Donot get the value #here**
        #print(self.model.value1.get())
        #result= self.model.recogniseButton(caption)
        #self.view.value_var1.set(result)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Controller()
    app.main()
```

view.py
[EDITS Made]

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class genTool(tk.Toplevel):
    BUTTON_CAPTION =['Button2']
    def __init__(self, parent,controller):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._make_entry()
        self._make_buttons()
        self.controller=controller


    def _make_entry(self):
        self.value_var2=tk.StringVar()
        self.ent =tk.Entry(self, textvariable= self.value_var2)
        self.ent.grid(row=2,column=1)
    def _make_buttons(self):
        for caption in self.BUTTON_CAPTION:
            btn=tk.Button(
                self, text= caption, command =(
                lambda button= caption: self.controller.on_button_click(button)
                )
                )
            btn.grid(row=3,column=2)

class View(tk.Tk):
    PAD =10
    BUTTON_CAPTIONS =['Button1']
    # self is place holder for object name
    def __init__(self, controller):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Application")
        self.controller = controller
        self.value_var2=tk.StringVar()
        self._make_main_frame()
        self._make_entry()
        self._make_buttons()


    def main(self):

        self.mainloop()

    def _make_entry(self):
        self.value_var1=tk.StringVar()
        self.ent =tk.Entry(self, textvariable= self.value_var1)
        self.ent.pack()
    def _make_buttons(self):

        for caption in self.BUTTON_CAPTIONS:
            btn=tk.Button(
                self, text= caption, command =(
                lambda button= caption: self.controller.on_button_click(button)
                )
                )
            btn.pack()


    def open_window(self):
        about = genTool(self,self.controller)
        about.grab_set()
    def _make_main_frame(self):
        menu = tk.Menu(self)
        menu = tk.Menu(self)
        file_menu = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
        file_menu.add_command(label="otherwin",command=self.open_window)
        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)
        self.config(menu=menu)
```

Model.py

```
class Model:

    def __init__(self):
        self.value1 =''
        self.value2 =''
    def recogniseButton(self, caption):

        if caption == 'Button1':
            print('Inside the Model Button1  registered. ')
            self.value= ''
            return self.value
        if caption == 'Button2':
            print("Inside the Model Button2  registered. This button is  toplevel")
            self.value= ''
            return self.value
```

Comment: `class genTool` does not hold a reference to `self.controller`

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Thanks for the response . I edited the code and added self.controller=controller in the class genTool. I am able to receive the buttonclicks  from  second window. But i cannot still get  the  numbers  that i enter   in the entry wiget on second window      The problem is with self.model.value2=self.view.value_var2 line in the controller.py

Comment: @ReblochonMasque  I understand the problem but i donot understand the solution. In the line  self.model.value2= self.view.value_var2 in  controller.py.  I should do self.model.value2= self.genTool.value_var2 .  But that throws in error.  I need to do something like self.genTool=genTool(??)  in the init of controller.py. But i donot know what argument i should pass inside brackets. Can you please help me with that.